# Setting Value of Cookie by simple JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to save a cookie by making call to a simple function. Following is my code:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<button onclick="alpha()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function alpha(){
var now = new Date();
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
document.cookie="name=" + "PeterMartin";
document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"
}
</script>

</body> 

</html>
```

I have taken help from the following website:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

However, I can see their function is able to save cookie in my local, but same I cannot find by my own more customized function. Basically, we both are doing same thing, but why my code is not able to save the cookie as they did as in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a variable called `now` and set it to "a month ago". (This is a very bad name for the variable).

You then tell the cookie to expire then.

Since "a month ago" is *in the past*, it expires immediately so isn't set.

> Basically, we both are doing same thing

The tutorial you link to has `+ 1` where you have `- 1`. It says that "`now`" (still a terrible name) is a month in the future. The cookie won't expire until then.

Comment: There isn't enough in your question to go on … but wild speculation suggests that maybe you aren't accessing the page over HTTP so there is no hostname to associate the cookie with.

Comment: Yes I was doubleClicking the file. When, I tried on XAMPP over localhost, it was able to save the cookie. Doesn't cookie saved just by double clicking file. (It happens when we set localStorage or sessionStorage)